# Прилагательное от слова буй

Tags: словообразование, прилагательные

Какое прилагательное от слова "буй" (поплавок для указания места на воде)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Буйковый.**

Источник: словари Кузнецова и Ефремовой.

Пример со словаря:
*Буйковый трос.*

буйковый 1. ***буй***, буёк, связанный с ним 2. Свойственный **бую**, буйку, характерный для них.

Comment: У Кузнецова этого нету, однако.

Comment: Но слово-то есть.

Answer (score 2):

Нормированного, судя по всему, нет, а у водников используется б**у**евый.

В словарях, к сожалению, достоверной информации я не обнаружил, но в текстах встречается.

Тут проблема не в неблагозвучности, а в том, чтобы отделить это значение от омонимичного диалектного "буевый" = буйный, которое есть у Даля.

Ну вот из гугл-книги пример, не оставляющий сомнения.

> Буевый свисток-сирена использует раскачивание буя на воде, в
>   результате чего в сопло свистка входит воздушная струя и раздается
>   печальный стон.-

(+)
Я не отрицаю существования слова "буйковый", но никто, кроме Ефремовой, не соотносит буйковый с буем. Только с буйком.  Тут возможно недоразумение. Буек - это не "маленький буй", это просто буй, как синоним. То есть по значению "буйковый" может означать "относящийся к бую", но это уже опосредовано, через синонимичность. Не рекомедовал бы считать прилагательным, **образованным** от "буй". Все-таки оно образовано от буйка, вряд ли кто в том усомнится.